# ¿Cómo limitar el acceso a una página web para que sólo sea accesible desde otra página web?

Tags: html, web, formularios, aplicación-web, permisos

Estoy creando un sitio web estilo formulario. La idea es que cada vez que el usuario responde una serie de preguntas, "avanza" de página web. Por ejemplo, está en "preguntas1.html" y cuando responde pasa a "preguntas2.html". Sin embargo, no quiero que "preguntas2.html" sea accesible, sin antes haber pasado por "preguntas1.html".

¿Cómo puedo limitar el acceso a esa segunda página para que sólo sea accesible, si la persona ya pasó por la primera?

Comment: Puedes pasar un parámetro por la URL en pregunta1 y luego en pregunta numero2 hacer una condición que si no esta llegando tu parámetro, entonces haga otra cosa. ya sea volver a pregunta uno o como usted quiera.

Comment: Pero esa es solo una forma de hacerlo, puedes guardar en base de datos lo que el usuario introdujo en pregunta uno y luego en pregunta2 hacer una condición y verificar el la tabla de la base de datos pregunta1 contenga información introducida por ese usuario, en caso de que no, pues entonces redirige o has lo que creas conveniente.

Comment: Las preguntas amplias y basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Answer (score 2):

Si las paginas webs se encuentran en el mismo dominio y puerto, puedes hacer uso de `localStorage` para saber por donde ha pasado el usuario.

Por ejemplo, en preguntas1;

```
localStorage.setItem('preguntas1', 'si') // Local storage solo puede guardar strings
```

Y en preguntas2, comprobar ese valor y de no ser el requerido expulsar al usuario o hacer una "autodestrucción", en función de lo que quieras implementar:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('preguntas1') !== 'si') document.body.innerHTML = ''
```

Ten en cuenta de que si no haces uso de un backend que lleve control, básicamente tienes que tener toda la lógica y datos "expuestos" en el frontend.